# Graph with std::vectors?

Tags: c++, vector

I thought that a cool way of using vectors could be to have one vector class template hold an two separate int variables for x/y-coordinates to graph.

example:

```
std::vector<int, int> *name*;
// First int. being the x-intercept on a graph
// Second int. being the y-intercept on a graph
```

(I also understand that I could just make every even/odd location or two separate vectors to classify each x/y-coordinate, but for me I would just like to see if this could work)

However, after making this vector type, I came across an issue with assigning which int within the vector will be written to or extracted from. Could anyone tell me how to best `select` and `std::cout` both x/y ints appropriately?

P.S. - My main goal, in using vectors this way, is to make a very basic graph output to Visual Studio terminal. While being able to change individual x/y-intercepts by 'selecting' and changing if needed. These coordinates will be outputted to the terminal via for/while loops.

*Also, would anyone like to list out different ways to best make x/y-coordinates with different containers?*

Comment: A vector is a kind of dynamic array, and as an array its element can only be of a single type. You need some other data-structure in conjunction with `std::vector` to be able to handle pairs of values, like for example [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question rather broad, in other words it is asking for a bit too much. I will just try to give you some pointers from which you can work your way to what you like.

**A) equidistant x**

If your `x` values are equidistant, ie `0, 0.5, 1, 1.5` then there is no need to store them, simply use a

```
std::vector<int> y;
```

if the number of variables is not known at compile time, otherwise a

```
std::array<int,N> y;
```

**B) arbitrary x**

There are several options that depend on what you actually want to do. For simply storing `(x,y)`-pairs and printing them on the screen, they all work equally well.

**map**

```
std::map<int,int> map_x_to_y = { { 1,1}, {2,4}, {3,9}};
// print on screen
for (const auto& xy : map_x_to_y) {
   std::cout << xy.first << ":" xy.second;
}
```

**a vector of pairs**

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> vector_x_and_y = { { 1,1}, {2,4}, {3,9}};
```

Printing on screen is actually the same as with `map`. The advantage of the map is that it has its elements ordered, while this is not the case for the vector.

**C) not using any container**

For leightweight calculations you can consider to not store the `(xy)` pairs at all, but simply use a function:

```
int fun(int x) { return x*x; }
```

**TL;DR / more focussed**

A vector stores one type. You cannot have a `std::vector<int,int>`. If you look at the documentation of `std::vector` you will find that the second template parameter is an allocator (something you probably dont have to care about for some time). If you want to store two values as one element in a vector you either have to use `std::vector<std::pair<double,double>>` or a different container.

**PS**

I used `std::pair` in the examples above. However, I do consider it as good practice to name things whenever I can and leave `std::pair` for cases when I simply cannot give names better than `first` and `second`. In this spirit you can replace `std::pair` in the above examples with a

```
struct data_point {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for! Your example of "a vector of pairs" is what I was trying to explain. I am just not too informed about using std::pair yet.

Comment: @DanielEscobedo seems like the tl;dr would have been enough ;). There is not much to know about `std::pair`. It holds two values called `first` and `second`, thats basically all

Comment: @DanielEscobedo note the PS, `std::pair` is rather useful, but often using something more explicit can make code way more readable

Comment: @DanielEscobedo only now I realized that using `double` as key in a  map can be problematic. I changed all `double` in my examples back to `int`. If you need `double`s, just drop me a comment.

Comment: @DanielEscobedo you have to read `first` and `second` seperately, just as you would read `int`s. Don't get me wrong, but comments are not for extended discussion. If you have a new question, maybe open a new question

Comment: @DanielEscobedo it is a different question that you should ask in a seperate question. Questions should have one question.

Comment: Alright, I'll make the separate question in the coming days. School you know. Thanks for your time!